# Remove special characters in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsattributedstring, catextlayer

In my app to show text in `CATextLayer`(change colors for characters),using `NSMutableAttributedString` to change colors,i want remove special characters in `NSMutableAttributedString` to show PopUp view, but didn't know how to remove special characters, to help to solve problem

i want like this type of o/p

```
"code" to code  //in NSMutableAttributedString, not in NSString
```

Answer (score 1):

to remove such characters you simply write something like this:

```
NSMutableString* mutableString = ...;
[mutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, mutableString.length)];
```

Note that symbol " is written as \" - this one is called an escape sequence.
Here is a list of such special characters in C - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: iam explained, i want NSMutableAttributedString not NSMutableString, NSMutableString is not set to CATextLayer

Comment: just use NSMutableString at first, remove unnecessary characters and then create NSMutableAttributedString using your modified NSMutableString.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...This may help you.

```
NSMutableString *unfilteredString = @"!@#$%^&*()_+|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"] invertedSet];
NSMutableString *resultString = [[unfilteredString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog (@"Result: %@", resultString);
```

Comment: how to use NSMutableString in CATextLayer,you use NSMutableAttributedString

Answer (score 0):

You can give try to this may it fits in your code:

```
 NSMutableString *mutableStrng = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1000];
[mutableStrng setString:@"my name is i#pho#ne"];

[mutableStrng replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,
 mutableStrng.length)];
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAtrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString
 alloc]initWithString:mutableStrng];
```